# How to stop a Topshelf service based on a cancellation token in Service Fabric?

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, topshelf

I have a stateful service that runs under Service Fabric using Topshelf. The problem is that on upgrade I get an error because the service doesn't stop(RunAsync' reported Warning for property 'RunAsyncSlowCancellation') when RunAsync method fires the CancelationToken. How can I stop the service using the token?

```
public static TopshelfExitCode RunServiceHost(CancellationToken token)
{
  return HostFactory.Run(x =>
  { 
      x.Service<MyService>(s =>
      {
          s.ConstructUsing(name => new MyService());
          s.WhenStarted((tc,a) => tc.Start(a));
          s.WhenStopped((tc, a) =>tc.Stop(a));
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but may I know why you decided to go with TopShelf instead of Worker Servies? (or was this an old app?)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to use `HostControl` `a` to stop the service when the token is cancelled, by [registering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=netcore-3.1) a callback using (`CancellationToken.Register`).

Make sure to enable shutdown:

```
s.EnableShutdown();
```